# String Comparison to NA Fails in If Statement

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, if-statement, string-comparison

I'm using Python 2.7 to convert my tabular data into matrix and I'm doing some analyses as well for that I'm checking if the cell has NA (it was an R output and I put NAs for missing data points). If the cell has an NA, I don't do any analyses, just pass to the other one.

But it works for some of them (first three rows) but it doesn't work at the 4th row. The value is again NA and I'm checking it in the same way.

Code:

```
def findMax(l, i):
    r = []
    for x in range(0, 3):
        if not l[i] == "NA": # Problem
            print l[i]
            if float(l[i]) <= 15:
                if not l[i-1] == "NA":
                    if float(l[i-1]) <= 0.05:
                        if not l[i-2] == "NA":
                            r.append(float(l[i-2]))

        i = i+12
    if len(r) != 0:
        return max(r)
    else:
        return 0


fIn = open("D:/projects/salmon/rawData_full.csv", "r")
fOut = open("D:/projects/salmon/dataAsMatrix.txt", "w")
fOut.write("Prot"+"\t"+"2 min"+"\t"+"5 min"+"\t"+"10 min"+"\t"+"20 min"+"\n")

for line in fIn:
    cols = line.split(";");
    if cols[6] != "NA":
        hgnc_symbol = cols[6];
        vals = [findMax(cols, 9), findMax(cols, 12), findMax(cols, 15), findMax(cols, 18)]
        m = max(vals)
        if m != 0:
            mi = [i for i, j in enumerate(vals) if j == m] # Problem
            if mi == [0]:
                fOut.write(hgnc_symbol+"\t"+"1"+"\t"+"0"+"\t"+"0"+"\t"+"0"+"\n")
            elif mi == [1]:
                fOut.write(hgnc_symbol+"\t"+"0"+"\t"+"1"+"\t"+"0"+"\t"+"0"+"\n")
            elif mi == [2]:
                fOut.write(hgnc_symbol+"\t"+"0"+"\t"+"0"+"\t"+"1"+"\t"+"0"+"\n")
            elif mi == [3]:
                fOut.write(hgnc_symbol+"\t"+"0"+"\t"+"0"+"\t"+"0"+"\t"+"1"+"\n")

fIn.close()
fOut.close()
```

Output of this particular code from CMD:

```
D:\projects\salmon>python processDataAsMatrix.py
17.278
16.37
13.072
11.251
23.81
4.3903
8.284
22.255
5.9456
25.727
15.511
13.448

18.857
17.056
15.106
33.84
3.9582
5.4985

18.857
17.056
15.106
33.84
3.9582
5.4985

NA

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "processDataAsMatrix.py", line 29, in <module>
    vals = [findMax(cols, 9), findMax(cols, 12), findMax(cols, 15), findMax(cols
, 18)]
  File "processDataAsMatrix.py", line 8, in findMax
    if float(l[i]) <= 15:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: NA
```

Table:

```
1st row: ZYX    0.030963842 0.44073 17.278  0.026328939 0.34735 11.251  -0.020729408    0.40571 8.284   0.12169113  0.047   25.727  -0.038389092    0.23603 16.37   -0.028881936    0.39508 23.81   0.017909396 0.41499 22.255  0.258158193 0.021821    15.511  -0.01200769 0.33594 13.072  0.049101678 0.34596 43.903  0.019365575 0.44196 59.456  0.157124196 0.19583 13.448
2nd row: ZYX    0.046846204 0.31797 18.857  0.146097014 0.0034837   15.106  0.221048912 0.0011114   33.84   0.492229415 3.61e-07    39.582  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0.011612729 0.49258 17.056  -0.076600534    0.071586    NA  0.371141778 7.49e-05    NA  0.507383556 0.0017682   54.985
3rd row: ZYX    0.046846204 0.32115 18.857  0.146097014 0.0032917   15.106  0.221048912 0.00099106  33.84   0.492229415 2.27e-07    39.582  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0.011612729 0.49293 17.056  -0.128999496    0.01102 NA  0.220709405 0.011875    NA  0.507383556 0.0017682   54.985
4th row: ZYX    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: Is it possible the string value has whitespace in it (e.g., `"NA "` or something)?

Comment: Try printing the value with `repr(l[i])` and see what is actually in the string.

Comment: You really should learn about [boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) instead of nesting `if`s five levels deep.

Comment: So true, it wasn't not `"NA "` but is was `NA\n` so that's why it won't match. I didn't know about `repr`. So I tried to `strip` it but it didn't work, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I know those operations but I felt here I need to go step by step because I don't want to analyze it it's more than 15 for example. But I guess I could do `if not (l[i] == NA and l[i] > 15)` and making whole three ifs right?

Comment: @Gungor: Boolean operators short-circuit. If you have `if a and b:`, and `a` is `False`, then `b` won't even be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for helping, `repr` has shown that the rows contained `\n` so I just had to do this: `line = line.rstrip()`. Now, it works.